# Solr query with white spaces and with query and operation

Tags: solr

I am working on a search solution in my project and it all working fine except one scenario. The search query operation is AND (q.op=AND), when I search for something ex: `40486 52P.57` it is not giving any results (here the query is being prepared in the java), but when I search the same in solr admin panel it gives the correct results. In my java code I am escaping the search query so the query being passed to solr like `q : 40486\\ 52P.57`, but when I execute it in solr admin it was like `q : 40486 52P.57`.

**Note: the two words in the above search query belong to two different fields.**

Another thing I have noticed was that if the words in the search query belong to the same field then results are coming fine without any issue, for ex: `40486 67` where both the words belong to same field and the query from my java code was `q: 40486\\ 67` and in solr admin it was `q : 40486 67` but in both cases it works fine.

I could not see any problem here, can someone please help me on this?

**Update**

I found the root cause why it is not working. The issue is that with the escaping the space. Actually I am using the individual fields in `qf` for searching for 100% match, I mean `mm=100` in this case. So escaping the space will be making the query as `q : 40486\\ 52P.57` and giving no results, but if I use multifield with all the searchable fields in it then it is giving the results even when the query is `q : 40486\\ 52P.57`. Is it a limitation with edismax in solr? can someone please help me how to fix this without creating the multifield? My expectation is that it should work even after escaping the space using the individual fields in `qf` parameter.

**Example index:**

```
{
productNumber : 40486754,
productShot : 52P.57 UTM, 
description : something,
general_search {
  40486754,
  52P.57 UTM,
  something
}
},
{
productNumber : 12345,
productShot : 52P.57 ABC, 
description : xzy,
general_search {
  12345,
  52P.57 ABC,
  xzy
}
}
```

**Example queries:**
**Query 1:**

`qt=/select&q.op=AND&defType=edismax&q=40486\+52P.57&qf=productNumber+productShot+description`

**Query 2:**

`qt=/select&q.op=AND&defType=edismax&q=40486 52P.57&qf=productNumber+productShot+description`

**Query 3:**

`qt=/select&q.op=AND&defType=edismax&q=40486\+52P.57&qf=general_search`

in the above queries Query 2 and 3 are working but not Query 1

Comment: I would suggest to add `debug=true` to your queries and, in the response, look at the `debug/parsedQuery` value and see if you can spot what is being parsed different between them.

Comment: Hi @HectorCorrea sorry for late response. Yes I did that and the issue was that the whitespace was escaped, when I did not escape whitespace it works as expected. Actually when whitespace was escaped the search was like "40486 52P.57" and treated as a single word, and when space was not escaped it was like two different words 40486 and 52P.57 so it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with escaping at whitespace. When I escape the whitespace it was treated like single word "40486 52P.57" and when space was not escaped it was treated like two different words 40486 and 52P.57 so it works fine.